# Authentication required of sender

Tags: php, email

I was trying to send mail following way. But the `mail` was returning true but mail wasn't sent.

```
<?php

    $digits = 4;
    $random = rand(pow(10, $digits-1), pow(10, $digits)-1);
        $to = "mail@gmail.com";
        $subject = "Verification code of Life Helper";
        
        $message = "<b>Hello, ".$username."</b>. Your verification code is : ".$random;
        
        $header = "sender@gmail.com \r\n";
        $header .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
        $header .= "Content-type: text/html\r\n";
        
        var_dump(mail ($to,$subject,$message,$header));
        $response["value"] = "sent";
        $response["message"] = $random;

?>
```

After looking at /var/mail/daemon I found the following message. The following message says authentication of sender is required. But I don't know how to solve it. I searched on the internet people using PHPMailer also faced the problem. How can I fix it?

```
   ----- Transcript of session follows -----
... while talking to smtp.gmail.com.:
>>> MAIL From:<daemon@localhost.localdomain> SIZE=723
<<< 530-5.7.0 Authentication Required. Learn more at
<<< 530 5.7.0  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=WantAuthError a4-20020a1709027d8400b00186fd3951f7sm1124783plm.211 - gsmtp
554 5.0.0 Service unavailable

--29TBxS4s014214.1667044768/localhost.localdomain
Content-Type: message/delivery-status

Reporting-MTA: dns; localhost.localdomain
Received-From-MTA: DNS; localhost.localdomain
Arrival-Date: Sat, 29 Oct 2022 07:59:25 -0400

Final-Recipient: RFC822; mail@gmail.com
Action: failed
Status: 5.7.0
Diagnostic-Code: SMTP; 530-5.7.0 Authentication Required. Learn more at
Last-Attempt-Date: Sat, 29 Oct 2022 07:59:28 -0400

--29TBxS4s014214.1667044768/localhost.localdomain
Content-Type: text/rfc822-headers

Return-Path: <daemon@localhost.localdomain>
Received: from localhost.localdomain (localhost.localdomain [127.0.0.1])
    by localhost.localdomain (8.15.2/8.15.2/Debian-22ubuntu3) with ESMTP id 29TBxP4s014212
    for <mail@gmail.com>; Sat, 29 Oct 2022 07:59:25 -0400
Received: (from daemon@localhost)
    by localhost.localdomain (8.15.2/8.15.2/Submit) id 29TBxP24014211;
    Sat, 29 Oct 2022 07:59:25 -0400
Date: Sat, 29 Oct 2022 07:59:25 -0400
Message-Id: <202210291159.29TBxP24014211@localhost.localdomain>
To: billyistiak001@gmail.com
Subject: Verification code of Life Helper
X-PHP-Originating-Script: 1000:index.php
From:sender@gmail.com
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-type: text/html
```

I looked at /var/mail/daemon, I saw that authentication is required of the sender. But I searched in internet but couldn't found anything. Lastly, I was expecting to successfully send email.

I followed [the tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=64nSHXGsmpo) in Windows 11 and it's working well. After watching the tutorial, I just realized the password I entered in Linux was same as my gmail account's password not the "App Password". Now, I have forgotten how I had set up the password, (I am using `sendmail`) so I can't solve the problem now. Can you please guide how to check what I used? The `php.ini` is ok.
I had executed the script, I can remember

```
sudo apt-get install libsasl2-2 libsasl2-modules sasl2-bin
```

But I didn't install postfix as said [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/47618). I remember it was telnet. But I can't find how to re-edit 'that' page.

Comment: Did you look at the link the error message included? Have you manually set up SMTP connection to gmail?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't download the ssmtp. So I started giving it a try.

```
sudo apt-get install mailutils
sudo apt-get install ssmtp
nano /etc/ssmtp/ssmtp.conf
```

add the following line in the page `/etc/ssmtp/ssmtp.conf`

```
mailhub=smtp.gmail.com:587
useSTARTTLS=YES
AuthUser=Your@email-address.com
AuthPass=I have written below what you have to write here.
TLS_CA_File=/etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt
```

Visit
`https://myaccount.google.com/u/1/security` (myaccount google's security page) then turn on 2 factor then below the 2 factor function you will see "App passwords" click on that, enter your gmail's password `Select app = Mail` and `select device= your device name` then click on generate a password will appear which you will have to use in AuthPass.

In `/opt/lampp/etc/php.ini`

```
SMTP=smtp.gmail.com
; http://php.net/smtp-port
smtp_port=587

; For Win32 only.
; http://php.net/sendmail-from
sendmail_from = your@email-address.com

; For Unix only.  You may supply arguments as well (default: "sendmail -t -i").
; http://php.net/sendmail-path
sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i
```

by default there will be semi-color before sendmail_path (also sometimes in sendmail_from) you have to remove that.

Comment: Some said ssmtp is deprecated, but I don't know since it's working fine for me.